# Dialogflow: Working with google.protobuf objects in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I built a python Dialogflow class to return as response as a string to be used for sending SMS messages. The returned string is a complex list of dictionaries with nested lists.

```
class DialogFlow():
    """
    A class to authenticate and point to a specific Dialogflow Agent. This will
    allow for multiple agents to be selected based on user response without
    having to create multiple separate functions
    """
    def __init__(self, project_id, language_code, session_id):
        self.project_id = project_id
        self.language_code = language_code
        self.session_id = session_id

    def detect_intent_response(self, text):
        """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.
        Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
        of the conversation."""

        session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
        session = session_client.session_path(self.project_id, self.session_id)

        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=self.language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        return_text = response.query_result.fulfillment_messages

        return str(return_text)
```

When building the object and calling the detect_intent_response method, the object returned is a google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer:

`[text {
  text: "Foo"
}
, text {
  text: "Bar"
}
, text {
  text: "Char"
}
]`

After several hours of searching, I discovered the google.protobuf library has a Module "json_format" that allows serializing to JSON or converting to a python dictionary, so I modified the class in the following manner:

```
response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        responses = MessageToDict(response, preserving_proto_field_name=True)
        desired_response = responses['query_result']

        return str(desired_response.get('fulfillment_messages', {}))
```

Which returns a complex list with nested dictionaries.

`[{'text': {'text': ['Foo']}}, {'text': {'text': ['Bar']}}, {'text': {'text': ['Char']}}]`

The desired result would return the following in a string format

`Foo
Bar
Char`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The goal for either return method is to extract the text as three separate strings

Comment: Is there anything else I can add for further clarification? There must be a way to convert these data types.